# Interpreting non-linear lme {nlme} models

Tags: r, lme4-nlme

I have the following model, which I fit using `lme` in the package `nlme`:

```
lme(∆T ~ Treatment 
          + sin(2*pi*hours/24) + cos(2*pi*hours/24),
          random = ~ 1 | Site.ID/Location.number, 
          data=data.30min.autumn,
          correlation = corAR1(form=~hours))
```

With data of the following structure:

```
'data.frame':   4594 obs. of  18 variables:
 $ Date          : Date, format: "2017-04-16" "2017-04-16" "2017-04-16" ...
 $ Time          : Factor w/ 288 levels "1:00:00 AM","1:00:00 PM",..: 62 62 62 62 62 62 50 50 50 50 ...
 $ Date.Time     : POSIXct, format: "2017-04-16 23:30:00" "2017-04-16 23:30:00" "2017-04-16 23:30:00" ...
 $ Treatment  : Factor w/ 2 levels "MAIN","NEXT": 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 ...
 $ Location.number: Factor w/ 27 levels "2","3","5","6",..: 11 12 5 6 3 4 11 12 5 6 ...
 $ Site.ID       : Factor w/ 14 levels "3","25","88",..: 9 9 12 12 13 13 9 9 12 12 ...
 $ Ambient.T     : num  13.2 13.2 13.2 13.2 13.2 ...
 $ Chamber.temp  : num  17.1 17 16.1 17.2 14.2 ...
 $ ∆T            : num  3.96 3.8 2.9 4.05 1.02 1.78 4.94 4.78 3.09 4.09 ...
 $ hours         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 -0.5 -0.5 -0.5 -0.5 ...
```

Where `hours` was set in the following way:

```
dt <- data.30min.autumn$Date.Time

dt1 <- as.POSIXlt(dt)

ts1 <- ts(dt1$hour)

data.30min.autumn$hours <- as.numeric(difftime(dt1, dt1[1], units = 'hours'))
```

The output for the model is as follows:

```
Linear mixed-effects model fit by REML
 Data: data.30min.autumn 
       AIC      BIC    logLik
  11187.05 11238.51 -5585.527

Random effects:
 Formula: ~1 | Site.ID
        (Intercept)
StdDev:   0.9106071

 Formula: ~1 | Location.number %in% Site.ID
        (Intercept)  Residual
StdDev:   0.5446349 0.8147144

Correlation Structure: ARMA(1,0)
 Formula: ~hours | Site.ID/Location.number 
 Parameter estimate(s):
     Phi1 
0.9185445 
Fixed effects: ∆T ~ Treatment + sin(2 * pi * hours/24) + cos(2 * pi *   hours/24) 
                            Value Std.Error   DF   t-value p-value
(Intercept)             1.2817408 0.4268638 4578  3.002693  0.0027
TreatmentNEXT          -0.2242362 0.3418594    6 -0.655931  0.5362
sin(2 * pi * hours/24)  0.5564014 0.1077713 4578  5.162797  0.0000
cos(2 * pi * hours/24)  1.9236595 0.0869060 4578 22.134933  0.0000
 Correlation: 
                       (Intr) C.NEXT s(*p*h
Chamber.typeNEXT       -0.400              
sin(2 * pi * hours/24) -0.016  0.000       
cos(2 * pi * hours/24) -0.171  0.000  0.067

Standardized Within-Group Residuals:
      Min        Q1       Med        Q3       Max 
-7.360529 -1.537524  0.190982  1.921293 10.546600 

Number of Observations: 4594
Number of Groups: 
                    Site.ID Location.number %in% Site.ID 

                  7                            14
```

What I am struggling with is how I should be interpreting the coefficients in the model. I haven't had much exposure to time series analyses like this and I can't seem to find anything online (there's much on how to make the models, but little on interpreting your output).

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're struggling with periodic components. The second and third term of your equation represent a periodic component of the outcomes. The length of the period is in days. A wave makes one full cycle in 24 hours.

When you have a sum of sine and cosine, it means that you have one perfect wave that is shifted in phase. So the two coefficients can be converted into an amplitude and the phase, while the frequency is predetermined in your case at 24 hours.

Use simple trigonometry to convert your equation into 
$$\Delta T=1.28-0.22\times TreatmentNEXT +2 \sin(2 \pi \times hours/24+1.3)$$

This means that the perfect wave with an amplitude $\approx2$ is added to the response with a frequency 1 day and the first peak $\approx 2$ hours from time 0